# I can not open a Preview for my software in gitpod

Tags: python, json, preview, gitpod

I am trying to make that flappybirdAI tutorial, but I can't control my work, as I can't get a preview from it.

I am using this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ps55secj7iU&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lwGZWXz5Qgta_YNX3_vLS2&index=2
(this is also my actual status at 16:52, WHERE HE IS OPENING A PREVIEW)

And here is the repository:
https://github.com/techwithtim/NEAT-Flappy-Bird

It is complete and working, but I can't find out, how the preview ist started.
I already tryed just adding my new trainingfile into that repository (can't get a review from it)
And also tryed to create a new one with my own package.json (review does not work)

In every tutorial i find, package.json seems to be necessary, but in that repository is no ".json".

So can anybody help me getting a preview from that running file, please?
(I can run it by the way without an ERROR.)

That is my actual code:

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800


#was ist wirklich ein pivotpunkt muss definiert werden. wsl nach prozenten der Laenge der Linie

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]  #scale ist für die Vergrößerung des Vogelbildes, load laed ein Bild in die Liste
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25 #max rotationswinkel
    ROT_VEL = 20 #rotation per frame
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y): # initialdaten des Vogels
        self.x = x #startposition Vogel
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0 #wie viel ist das Bild gekippt
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0 #geschwindigkeit Bild
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0 #welches Vogelbild wird gerade gezeigt? Für die Animation wichtig
        self.img = self.IMGS[0] #Bild bird1.png von oben

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5 #negativ, weil der Ursprung der Koordinatien links oben ist
        self.tick_count = 0 #wann das letzte mal gesprungen? wird zurückgesetzt um das physische Verhalten danach auszurichten (vllt wie lange ist der Einstieg her)
        self.height = self.y #von wo aus springt der Vogel (vllt wo Einstiegspunkt)    

    def move(self): #hier wird jeden Frame gesagt, dass der Vogel bewegt werden soll
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2 #macht den Parabelflug bzw die Geschwindigkeitsbewegung die das verursacht

        if d >= 16: #Geschwindigkeitsgrenze
            d = 16

        if d < 0: #Geschwindigkeit über 0, addiere Geschwindigkeit nach oben
            d -= 2  
        
        self.y = self.y + d #berechnet in welche Richtung der Vogel Geschwindigkeit hat

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION #limitert die Rotation des Bildes
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL
        
    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME: #Animation_Time ist die Anzahl an Frames solange ein Bild bleiben soll. damit ein gleichmäßiges Flattern entsteht, vervielfacht sich diese Zeit ich gleichen Abständen. Beim Fallen schlägt der Vogel mit keinen Flügeln mehr.
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 +1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2 #dadurch flattert der Vogel beim Sturzflug nicht

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center) #rotiert das Bild von der Mitte aus und nicht von links oben
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft) #Bild wird in das win(dow) geladen. blit ist wsl das schnelle kopieren und verschieben von Speicherinhalten

    def get_mask(self): #Kollision mit Objekten
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


def draw_window(win, bird): #zeichnet das Window
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0)) #blit ist die Zeichenfunktion
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update() #refresht den Display


def main(): #main loop vom Spiel
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)) #erstellt das Window

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        draw_window(win, bird)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

This is the interface with all it's stuff:
[the file mytry.py is the only thing I changed in that whole thing. The problems that it shows are also in flappy_bird.py showed as problems, but it works there anyway.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t1B8.png)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the preview opens automatically after workspace start.

Could you please try to click on `Ports 5900,6080` in the status bar (bottom right)? It opens a list of ports in the left panel where you could click on the world globe that appears next to port 6080 which opens the preview. Please have a look if your browser blocks popups.